# Implicit function problem exercises

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3$ be continuously differentiable functions from $\mathbb R^4$ to $\mathbb R$. Give sufficient conditions so that the equations $f_1(x,y,z, t)=0$, $f_2(x,y,z, t)=0$, $f_3(x,y,z, t)=0$ can be solved for x, y, z in terms of t.

My attempt: Let $f_1,f_2,f_3:\mathbb R^4\rightarrow \mathbb R$

Let $f:\mathbb R^4\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$  defined by $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$, then f is a smooth function. The differential matrix

$Df=\left[\begin{matrix}\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\\\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}\\\dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial z}\end{matrix}\right]$

I do not know how to step up from this. Please, help.

Comment: See the [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for the link.I have my book in the front of me. I wish I can understand how to interpret the problem.:).

Comment: I find the problem very vague. "Give sufficient conditions", well, about the conditions being exactly "The equations can be solved for $x,y,z$ in terms of $t$"? Then it's trivially true. Another possible set of conditions are those of the IFT, but then this is just the IFT, why ask such a question? Maybe the problem comes before the IFT? Does it come up before the IFT and after the inverse function theorem? Or maybe you just have a restricted version of the IFT available and you're supposed to use it to generalize to the standard IFT? I don't know.

Comment: This is my book,http://books.google.com/books?id=mMBY5jdjGfoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false the problem is on page 440, problem 10